# Does GCP Cloud Router not support BGP auth?

Tags: authentication, bgp, google-cloud-router

I wanted to configure on GCP Cloud Router a BGP session with BGP authentication (for on-premise connectivity / hybrid connectiviy), but cannot fine any option to set a password in the gcloud CLI or Web client?

Does GCP not support BGP authentication?

Here the command doc:

```
 gcloud help compute routers add-bgp-peer
 NAME
    gcloud compute routers add-bgp-peer - add a BGP peer to a Google Compute
        Engine router

 SYNOPSIS
    gcloud compute routers add-bgp-peer NAME --interface=INTERFACE
        --peer-asn=PEER_ASN --peer-name=PEER_NAME
        [--advertised-route-priority=ADVERTISED_ROUTE_PRIORITY]
        [--advertisement-mode=MODE] [--async]
        [--peer-ip-address=PEER_IP_ADDRESS] [--region=REGION]
        [--set-advertisement-groups=[GROUP,...]]
        [--set-advertisement-ranges=[CIDR_RANGE=DESC,...]]
        [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG ...]
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/routers/add-bgp-peer

I expected to have a BGP password parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Currently is not possible to configure BGP authentication in Cloud VPN, as the only components in the Cloud Router are:

- Name
- VPC Network
- Region
- Google ASN

But there is a public feature request in order to implement it, you can keep an eye on progress for it:
https://issuetracker.google.com/139927386